# How to remove file path that auto label on graph in gnuplot?

Tags: macos, gnuplot

I tried to use gnuplot to plot graph using data file the problem is that it always label data file's path on my graph. i don't know why

for example this line of code from script:

```
splot "../data/output/f1.dat" u 1:2:3
```

This `../data/output/f1.dat` will be labeled on my graph automatically

How to remove this text from my graph?

Additional information:

http://www.kinovea.org/help/en/125.html

might be like this case but i don't want "weightlift.txt" be labeled on the graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, i have to answer my question(again):

```
unset key
```

but side effect now is this remove also some useful legends that tell me about meaning of each line on a graph

Additional answer:

Ok, now if anybody want to remove auto-title(file name) without remove legend (description about meaning of each line on your graph) you can use this command

```
set key noautotitle
```

Hope this help anybody that have problem like me

Comment: SO actually encourages self-answers. It is a form of knowledge sharing which might help others in the future.

Comment: @LajosArpad I always find the way out at very last minute. And ashamed to answer my own question. but hope this help other in the future.

Comment: My friend, you are misunderstanding it. You are contributing to the site by adding your knowledge. You should be proud to be able to find out the answer for a question which was hard-enough to ask it online. This is an achievement and you should feel good about it instead of being ashamed.

Comment: You can also add a `notitle` option to the `splot` command to suppress the legend of you plot. Or you can specify a title name for you plot by adding `title "your plot title"` option to the `splot` command. The `plot` or `splot` command use your datafile's name (including path if you specify it) as the default title.

Comment: @LajosArpad and fronthem: I just found this answer “in the future” (ten years later), and it was exactly what I needed :-)